# issue of compiling wireshark source code with vs2013 under 64bit option

Tags: visual-studio-2013, compilation, 64-bit, wireshark

The environment is set as:

```
@echo off 
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio12.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" 

call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64

e:

cd  E:\Wireshark_Plugin\Source\wireshark-master

set  YES_I_KNOW_ABOUT_THE_DEPRECATION=1

set  VISUALSTUDIOVERSION=12.0

set MSVC_VARIANT=MSVC2013EE

set CYGWIN_PATH=E:\Software\Cygwin\bin

set WIRESHARK_BASE_DIR=E:\Wireshark_Plugin\Source\wireshark-master

set WIRESHARK_TARGET_PLATFORM=win64

set QT5_BASE_DIR=E:\Software\QT\5.6\msvc2013_64

::nmake -f Makefile.nmake verify_tools

::nmake -f Makefile.nmake setup

::nmake -f Makefile.nmake distclean

nmake -f Makefile.nmake all

pause
```

The compile result shown below failed

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 12.00.21005.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cd ..
        xcopy E:\Wireshark_Plugin\Source\wireshark-master\Wireshark-win64-libs\zlib-1.2.8-ws zlib.tmp /D /I /E /Y

        cd zlib.tmp
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" /
                   -f win32/Makefile.msc zlib1.dll AS=ml64 LOC="-I. -DASMV -DASMINF" OBJA="inffasx64.obj gvmat64.obj inffas8664.obj"

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 12.00.21005.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        ml64 -c -coff -Zi -I. -DASMV -DASMINF ./contrib/masmx64\inffasx64.asm
'ml64' is not internal or external command

NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'ml64' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Does anybody has the same problem as me?  I was confused about for almost one week, hope someone may help me.
Thanks all.

By the way, it has compiled successfully under 32bit option.
Then environment setting is as below:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"

e:

cd  E:\Wireshark_Plugin\Source\wireshark-master

set  YES_I_KNOW_ABOUT_THE_DEPRECATION=1

set  VISUALSTUDIOVERSION=12.0

set MSVC_VARIANT=MSVC2013EE

set CYGWIN_PATH=E:\Software\Cygwin\bin

set WIRESHARK_BASE_DIR=E:\Wireshark_Plugin\Source\wireshark-master

set WIRESHARK_TARGET_PLATFORM=win32

set QT5_BASE_DIR=E:\Software\QT\5.6\msvc2013_64

call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"  x86

::nmake -f Makefile.nmake verify_tools

::nmake -f Makefile.nmake setup

::nmake -f Makefile.nmake distclean

nmake -f Makefile.nmake all

pause
```

Comment: `vcvarsall` should have modified your path to include the location of ml64.exe.  What does your path look like?  And where is your copy of ml64.exe located?

Comment: Thanks David ,I will have a try then continue discuss with you.

Comment: Hi Sir, I modified " amd64" to "x86_amd64" in the bat file,and the problem disappeared.But another Link problem happened, below is the error description,please kindly help me have a check,what mistake I have made,Thanks David.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all for paying attention my question.I have resolved this issue.
It seems the Unicode setting problem.
Go to Control Panel->Region and Language->Language for the non-Unicode programs
In "Current language for non-Unicode programs", Change  to "English(United States)".